# How to cancel Task without exception?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I need to execute a kind of `LongRunning` task after a delay.
Each Task can be cancelled. I prefer `TPL` with `cancellationToken`.

Since my task is long running and before starting a task it has to be placed in dictionary I have to use `new Task()`. But I've faced different behavior - when task is created using `new Task()` after `Cancel()` it throws `TaskCanceledException` whereas a task created with `Task.Run` doesn't throw an exception.

Generally I need to recognize the difference and not get `TaskCanceledException`.

It's my code:

```
internal sealed class Worker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Guid, (Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)> _tasks =
        new Dictionary<Guid, (Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)>();

    public void ExecuteAfter(Action action, TimeSpan waitBeforeExecute, out Guid cancellationId)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var task = new Task(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(waitBeforeExecute, cts.Token);
            action();
        }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        cancellationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _tasks.Add(cancellationId, (task, cts));

        task.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public void ExecuteAfter2(Action action, TimeSpan waitBeforeExecute, out Guid cancellationId)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _tasks.Add(cancellationId, (Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(waitBeforeExecute, cts.Token);
            action();
        }, cts.Token), cts));
    }

    public void Abort(Guid cancellationId)
    {
        if (_tasks.TryGetValue(cancellationId, out var value))
        {
            value.cts.Cancel();
            //value.task.Wait();

            _tasks.Remove(cancellationId);
            Dispose(value.cts);
            Dispose(value.task);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var t in _tasks)
            {
                Dispose(t.Value.cts);
                Dispose(t.Value.task);
            }

            _tasks.Clear();
        }
    }

    private static void Dispose(IDisposable obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            obj.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log.Exception(ex);
        }
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action act = () => Console.WriteLine("......");

        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        using (var w = new Worker())
        {
            w.ExecuteAfter(act, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000), out var id);
            //w.ExecuteAfter2(act, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000), out var id);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            w.Abort(id);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

This approach also works without exception

```
public void ExecuteAfter3(Action action, TimeSpan waitBeforeExecute, out Guid cancellationId)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationId = Guid.NewGuid();

    _tasks.Add(cancellationId, (Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(waitBeforeExecute, cts.Token);
        action();
    }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default), cts)); ;
}
```

Comment: You can could check the task's `Status` property against the enum https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: how it can help me ? `Task.Run` does not throw exception whereas `new Task()` does. I need to get why it happens.

Comment: they all throw the exception dude

Comment: @JohnChris it's cause `//value.task.Wait();` I've just updated my code

Comment: @isxaker so just to be clear: they all throw the exception its just how the exception bubbles up, with the wait()- it shows up there as your are waiting for the return value from the the other thread

Comment: @isxaker you should probably keep the `value.task.wait` and catch that specific exception not a general exception

Comment: @JohnChris but I get the exception in this line `await Task.Delay(waitBeforeExecute, cts.Token);` not in `value.task.Wait();`

Comment: @isxaker *don't* use `new Task` at all. Tasks aren't threads, they are promises. There's no reason to use a cold task. `Task.Run` understands about cancellation and [returns a task in the cancelled state](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5756) if the token is already cancelled.

Comment: @isxaker as for your `worker` class, it's trying to do what *Task*, the TPL and the threadpool already do. When you call `Task.Run`, a new *promise* is created that's put in a queue for execution by a threadpool thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how i can specify that is gonna be a long running task using `Task.Run`

Comment: @isxaker Why do you want to do that? In fact, why do you want to create this class at all? What problem are you trying to solve? Simply running actions in the background is what `Task.Run` does. The [ActionBlock<>T](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-2.2) can be used to queue and process messages/jobs too.

Comment: Check [Performance Showdown of Producer/Consumer (Job Queues) Implementations in C# .NET](https://michaelscodingspot.com/performance-of-producer-consumer/). You'll see that using an ActionBlock is *very* simple and *very* fast. Using tasks by themselves won't really help writing a job queue as they are *based* on job queues (ie threadpools). That's why the `Thread-pool on demand` class doesn't use tasks and comes out the fastest. The Dataflow and Channel implementations use tasks to work the queue, not as queue elements

Comment: As for cancellation, your code breaks TPL's cancellation. The *client* is the one that should have access to the CancellationTokenSource and call cancel through it. In fact, the *clients* are the ones that should instantiate the CTS and only pass the cancellation token to other methods. Perhaps the client wants to use a timeout? Easily done by specifying a timeout when creating a CTS. Perhaps they want to abort based on *anoter* cancellation token? They can just pass it along, or even chain their own CTS with a source token. Both scenarios become a lot harder with that `Abort` method though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't need job queue(thread pool). I have quite simple task. After an event perform delayed action which can be cancelled. That all. I do not need all that complex staff to do that. And I do not want to provide access to cts for a client(for my task it's enough - cancellation logic can be hided)

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the inconsistent behavior is fundamentally incorrect usage of an async delegate in the first case. The `Task` constructors just don't receive `Func<Task>` and your asynchronous delegate is always interpreted as `async void` not `async Task` in case of using with constructor. If an exception is raised in an `async Task` method it's caught and placed into `Task` object which isn't true for an `async void` method, in that case exception just bubbles up out of the method to a synchronization context and goes under category of unhandled exceptions  (you can familiarize with details in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) Stephen Cleary article). So what happens in case of using constructor: a task which is supposed to initiate asynchronous flow is created and started. Once it reaches point when `Task.Delay(...)` returns a promise, the task completes and it has no more relationship to anything which happens in `Task.Delay` continuation (you can easily check in debugger by setting a breakpoint to `value.cts.Cancel()` that the task object in the `_tasks` dictionary has status `RanToCompletetion` while however the task delegate essentially is still running). When a cancellation is requested the exception is raised inside the `Task.Delay` method and without existence of any promise object is being promoted to app domain.

In case of `Task.Run` the situation is different because there are overloads of this method which are able to accept `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` and unwrap the tasks internally in order to return underlying promise instead of wrapped task which ensures proper task object inside the `_tasks` dictionary and proper error handling.

The third scenario despite the fact that it doesn't throw an exception it is partially correct. Unlike `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't unwrap underlying task to return promise, so task stored in the `_tasks` is just wrapper task, like in the case with constructor (again you can check its state with debugger). It however is able to understand `Func<Task>` parameters, so asynchronous delegate has `async Task` signature which allows at least to handle and store exception in the underlying task. In order to get this underlying task with `Task.Factory.StartNew` you need to unwrap the task by yourself with `Unwrap()` extension method.

The `Task.Factory.StartNew` isn't considered as a beast practice of creating tasks because of certain dangers related to its application (see [there](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)). It however can be used with some caveats if you need to apply specific options like `LongRunning` which cannot be directly applied with `Task.Run`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why I got down votes here but it's inspired me to update my answer.

### **UPDATED**

My full approach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var delayedWorker = new DelayedWorker())
            {
                delayedWorker.ProcessWithDelay(() => { Console.WriteLine("100"); }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), out var cancellationId_1);
                delayedWorker.ProcessWithDelay(() => { Console.WriteLine("200"); }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), out var cancellationId_2);
                delayedWorker.ProcessWithDelay(() => { Console.WriteLine("300"); }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), out var cancellationId_3);

                Cancel_3(delayedWorker, cancellationId_3);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static void Cancel_3(DelayedWorker delayedWorker, Guid cancellationId_3)
        {
            Task.Run(() => { delayedWorker.Abort(cancellationId_3); }).Wait();
        }

        internal sealed class DelayedWorker : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly object _locker = new object();
            private readonly object _disposeLocker = new object();
            private readonly IDictionary<Guid, (Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)> _tasks = new Dictionary<Guid, (Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)>();
            private bool _disposing;

            public void ProcessWithDelay(Action action, TimeSpan waitBeforeExecute, out Guid cancellationId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating delayed action...");
                CancellationTokenSource tempCts = null;
                CancellationTokenSource cts = null;

                try
                {
                    var id = cancellationId = Guid.NewGuid();

                    tempCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    cts = tempCts;

                    var task = new Task(() => { Process(action, waitBeforeExecute, cts); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                    _tasks.Add(cancellationId, (task, cts));
                    tempCts = null;

                    task.ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        lock (_disposeLocker)
                        {
                            if (!_disposing)
                            {
                                TryRemove(id);
                            }
                        }
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Created(cancellationId: {cancellationId})");
                    task.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (tempCts != null)
                    {
                        tempCts.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void Process(Action action, TimeSpan waitBeforeExecute, CancellationTokenSource cts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting delayed action...");
                cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(waitBeforeExecute);
                if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                lock (_locker)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Performing action...");
                    action();
                }
            }

            public bool Abort(Guid cancellationId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Aborting(cancellationId: {cancellationId})...");

                lock (_locker)
                {
                    if (_tasks.TryGetValue(cancellationId, out var value))
                    {
                        if (value.task.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("too late");
                            return false;
                        }

                        value.cts.Cancel();
                        value.task.Wait();

                        Console.WriteLine("Aborted");
                        return true;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Either too late or wrong cancellation id");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            private void TryRemove(Guid id)
            {
                if (_tasks.TryGetValue(id, out var value))
                {
                    Remove(id, value.task, value.cts);
                }
            }

            private void Remove(Guid id, Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
            {
                _tasks.Remove(id);

                Dispose(cts);
                Dispose(task);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                lock (_disposeLocker)
                {
                    _disposing = true;
                }

                if (_tasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var t in _tasks)
                    {
                        t.Value.cts.Cancel();
                        t.Value.task.Wait();

                        Dispose(t.Value.cts);
                        Dispose(t.Value.task);
                    }

                    _tasks.Clear();
                }
            }

            private static void Dispose(IDisposable obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    obj.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //log ex
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WaitOne inside task is not good because it's a blocking operation and may cause a shitstorm that is very hard to debug later.